# Prevent pasting cell contents in Spyder's console

Tags: spyder

I am using Spyder IDE, and I need some help with code blocks in it.

I am currently trying to work with code blocks, since I felt it removes the need to compile the whole program every time, and also the method of partial selection of code and running it.

I have checked Console settings in Preferences but couldn't find any solution..

But I have a problem
When I create a code block using **# %%** and write some code in it,
for example:

```py
    # %%
    a = input('Enter your first name: ')
    b = input('Enter your last name: ')
    print('\nYour name is',a,b)
```

When I run this code block, the whole code present in the block is pasted into the Console and then it is executed.

Is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: I don't understand what it is you want to avoid. What isn't working?

Comment: The code is working fine, but it is being pasted into the console every time it is executed, and it is annoying..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This is already solved and it'll be part of Spyder **4** (our next major version, to be released later in 2019).

For this version we added a function called `runcell`, which will run a cell without the need of pasting its entire contents into the console.